# In a Keras custom RNN cell, what are the dimensions of the inputs and outputs?

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network, tf.keras

The custom cell takes (*input,state*) and generates (*output,state*). I believe *input* is a tensor, and *state* is a list of tensors. From fighting through error messages it appears that the tensors carry along an extra dimension, but I'm not sure what that would be in the context of an RNN.  What is the other dimension for? And what is the expected output size/shape?

I'm using Tensorflow back end by the way.

Answer (score 2):

The cell input is a 3d tensor of shape (batch_size, timesteps, input_size) or (timesteps, batch_size, input_size) depending on how you unroll the input (if you select time_major attribute to be true or not). The state is a list of n tensors where each tensor has the shape (batch_size, hidden_state), where n is the number of RNN layers (or stacked RNN cells).

Comment: You are saying that all timesteps are presented to the cell simultaneously?  That doesn't seem consistent with the sequential feedback nature of the cell, i.e.: (out,state) = func(in,state).

Comment: I'll try to explain the whole rnn and how it works in keras. Let's say you're having an input of shape (batch_size, timesteps, input_size). You will first create an RNN layer. You can think about it as a wrapper for the cell, it will unroll the input on the time dimension. At each time, it will call the cell with the current input (1 timestamp) and state. Afterwards the output of the cell (output, state) it will be passed as input to the next cell and stored in a list. After all  timestamps have been processed the lists will be returned.

Comment: Right, so at the cell function  input, only one time is passed at a time.  So the shape into the cell would be (batch_size, input_size)?

Comment: Yes, the input inside the cell should have that shape.